# How can I format a decimal bound to TextBox without angering my users?

Tags: wpf, textbox, decimal, string-formatting

I'm trying to display a formatted decimal in a TextBox using data binding in WPF.

### Goals

Goal 1: When setting a decimal property in code, display 2 decimal places in the TextBox.

Goal 2: When a user interacts with (types in) the TextBox, don't piss him/her off.

Goal 3: Bindings must update source on PropertyChanged.

### Attempts

***Attempt 1: No formatting.***

Here we're starting nearly from scratch.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Violates Goal 1. `SomeDecimal = 4.5` will show "4.50000" in the TextBox.

***Attempt 2: Use StringFormat in the Binding.***

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=F2}" />
```

Violates Goal 2.  Say SomeDecimal is 2.5, and the TextBox is displaying "2.50".  If we select all and type "13.5" we end up with "13.5.00" in the TextBox because the formatter "helpfully" inserts decimals and zeros.

***Attempt 3: use Extended WPF Toolkit's MaskedTextBox.***

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

Assuming I'm reading the documentation correctly, the mask ##0.00 means "two optional digits, followed by a required digit, a decimal point, and two more required digits.  This forces me to say "the largest possible number that can go into this TextBox is 999.99" but let's say I'm ok with that.

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Value="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Mask="##0.00" />
```

Violates Goal 2.  The TextBox starts with `___.__` and selecting it and typing 5.75 yields `575.__`.  The only way to get 5.75 is to select the TextBox and type `<space><space>5.75`.

***Attempt 4: use Extended WPF Toolkit's DecimalUpDown spinner.***

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DecimalUpDown

```
<xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FormatString="F2" />
```

Violates Goal 3.  DecimalUpDown happily ignores UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.  One of the Coordinators on the Extended WPF Toolkit Codeplex page suggests a modified ControlTemplate at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/352551/.  This satisfies Goal 3, but violates Goal 2, exhibiting the same behavior as in Attempt 2.

***Attempt 5: Using style datatriggers, only use formatting if user is not editing.***

[Binding to a double with StringFormat on a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183922)

Even if this one satisfied all three goals, I wouldn't want to use it.  (A) Textboxes become 12 lines each instead of 1, and my application contains many, many textboxes.  (B) All my textboxes already have a Style attribute which points to a global StaticResource which sets Margin, Height, and other things.  (C) You may have noticed the code below sets the binding Path twice, which violates the DRY principal.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, StringFormat=F2}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=SomeDecimal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

All these uncomfortable things aside...

Violates Goal 2.  First, clicking on a TextBox which displays "13.50" suddenly makes it display "13.5000", which is unexpected.  Second, if starting with a blank TextBox, and I type "13.50", the TextBox will contain "1350".  I can't explain why, but pressing the period key doesn't insert decimals if the cursor is at the right end of the string in the TextBox.  If the TextBox contains a string with length > 0, and I reposition the cursor to anywhere except the right end of the string, I can then insert decimal points.

***Attempt 6: Do it myself.***

I'm about to embark on a jouney of pain and suffering, by either subclassing TextBox, or creating an attached property, and writing the formatting code myself.  It will be full of string manipulation, and cause substantial hairloss.

---

Does anyone have any suggestions for formatting decimals bound to textboxes that satisfies all the above goals?

Comment: Goal 2 is impossible. Users will always be pissed. ;)

Comment: Tried Attempt 1. `SomeDecimal = 4.5M` results in "4.5" displayed. `SomeDecimal = 4.50M` generates "4.50".

Comment: @Clemens if you play with textboxes/decimals/bindings/stringformat long enough you'll see the extra zeros.  I'm not sure what exactly causes it to happen, but it does happen.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this?

Comment: Nope, rolled my own thing.  Sigh.

Comment: What an absolute indictment of WPF that such a basic issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Related answer/thread in case it helps someone finding this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649007/stringformat-converterculture-and-a-textboxs-decimal-mark

Comment: I ended up using `StringFormat={}{0:0.0###}` on my bindings and created a custom behavior that moved the users cursor to after the decimal point when they press the period key ('.')

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor mind sharing that custom behavior?

Comment: @epalm posted it as an answer below, hope it helps, I know this annoyed me for the longest of times.

Answer (score 5):

Try to resolve that on ViewModel level. That it:

```
public class FormattedDecimalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly string _format;

        public FormattedDecimalViewModel()
            : this("F2")
        {

        }

        public FormattedDecimalViewModel(string format)
        {
            _format = format;
        }

        private string _someDecimalAsString;
        // String value that will be displayed on the view.
        // Bind this property to your control
        public string SomeDecimalAsString
        {
            get
            {
                return _someDecimalAsString;
            }
            set
            {
                _someDecimalAsString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SomeDecimalAsString");
                RaisePropertyChanged("SomeDecimal");
            }
        }

        // Converts user input to decimal or initializes view model
        public decimal SomeDecimal
        {
            get
            {
                return decimal.Parse(_someDecimalAsString);
            }
            set
            {
                SomeDecimalAsString = value.ToString(_format);
            }
        }

        // Applies format forcibly
        public void ApplyFormat()
        {
            SomeDecimalAsString = SomeDecimal.ToString(_format);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**SAMPLE**

Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding Path=SomeDecimalAsString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormattedDecimalViewModel formattedDecimalViewModel = new FormattedDecimalViewModel { SomeDecimal = (decimal)2.50 };
    tb.LostFocus += (s, e) => formattedDecimalViewModel.ApplyFormat(); // when user finishes to type, will apply formatting
    DataContext = formattedDecimalViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created the following custom behavior to move the users cursor to after the decimal point when using `StringFormat={}{0:0.00}`, which forces a decimal place to be present, however this can cause the following issue:

> Violates Goal 2. Say SomeDecimal is 2.5, and the TextBox is displaying "2.50". If we select all and type "13.5" we end up with "13.5.00" in the TextBox because the formatter "helpfully" inserts decimals and zeros.

I have hacked around this using a custom behavior that will move the users cursor to after the decimal place when they press the . key:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace GUI.Helpers.Behaviors
{
    public class DecimalPlaceHotkeyBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        #region Methods
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new DecimalPlaceHotkeyBehavior();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Event Methods
        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.OemPeriod || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Decimal)
            {
                var periodIndex = AssociatedObject.Text.IndexOf('.');
                if (periodIndex != -1)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.CaretIndex = (periodIndex + 1);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Initialization
        public DecimalPlaceHotkeyBehavior()
            : base()
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
<TextBox xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:GUI.Helpers.Behaviors" 
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
         Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Behaviors:DecimalPlaceHotkeyBehavior></Behaviors:DecimalPlaceHotkeyBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the WPF Extended Tookit Masked TextBox to implement an Input Mask:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

Example:

```
<toolkit:MaskedTextBox Mask="(000) 000-0000" Value="(555) 123-4567" 
IncludeLiterals="True" />
```

Comment: MaskedTextBox was already tried, see attempt 3 in the question.

Comment: I have no idea why my eyes missed that example. In your case, I would then override the KeyUp and KeyDown events on the textbox and force it to style it on the backend. Will it piss them off? Yes, because kenny is right: Users will always be pissed. However, this will give you the most control.